# Function to preserve evaluation on display?

Tags: evaluation, output

I'm looking for a function that applies the following behavior to an expression:

-When the expression is given as the full input, or as part of a function that cannot be evaluated, it remains in unevaluated form. 
-When the expression is used for a function, it is evaluated.

`Defer[]` won't evaluate it in a function. `Unevaluated[]` leaves itself in evaluated when used directly as output.

Essentially, I need a function `F[]` that will output the following:

- `F[1-1/2]` outputs `1-1/2`, NOT `1/2`
- `Times[F[1-1/2],5]` outputs `5/2`, NOT `(1-1/2)5`
- `Times[F[1-1/2],x]` outputs `(1-1/2)x`, NOT `x/2`

If the solution only works for a specific internal expression, that works, because I only need this for one function.

Comment: have a look at the documentation for `UpValues` and `HoldForm`.

Comment: Is `Times` your actual "specific internal" function?  Your third requirement is likely going to require knowledge of that function and special handing.

Answer (score 2):

Something along these lines?

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll];
f /: h_?headPredQ[b___, f[arg_], a___] := 
  With[{res = h[b, arg, a]}, res /; Hold[res] =!= Hold[h[b, arg, a]]];
Format[f[arg_]] := Defer[arg];
headPredQ[h_] := MemberQ[Attributes@h, NumericFunction];
```

**EDIT**

New version that contemplates the third case I had forgot (thanks @MichaelE2). This compares the evaluated result of the expression with the result of only applying attribute transformations like those of `Flat`, `Sequence` or `Orderless`. So, reorderings of arguments in a multiplication aren't interpreted as a real evaluation now

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst];
f /: h_?headPredQ[b___, f[arg_], a___] :=
  Block[{s}, 
   s /: h[s, args___] := Hold[h[args]]; 
   With[{res = h[b, arg, a]},
    res /; Hold[res] =!= h[s, b, arg, a]]];
Format[f[arg_]] := Defer[arg];
headPredQ[h_] := MemberQ[Attributes@h, NumericFunction];
```

Comment: For `Times[f[1 - 1/2], x]` I'm getting the output `x/2` and the OP seems to want `(1-1/2)x`.  Perhaps use something like `?(VectorQ[{#},NumericQ]&)` on `a` and `b`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 For `BlankNullSequence` patterns only the `NumericQ` condition needs to be specified.

Answer (score 1):

I like how Rojo's answer tests for evaluation in general, but it requires an additional fix as noted by Michael E2. So here is another approach where I interpret "evaluating" in the question as meaning "to yield a numerical result". This can be tested with `NumericQ`. Then I just have to take care of the non-numeric case by returning the `Defer`ed result and also stopping the potential recursion that will happen if `f[x]` is not inside another function:

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst];
f /: h_[a___, f[x_], b___] := 
  If[TrueQ@NumericQ[h[a, x, b]], h[a, x, b],
   Defer[h[a, x, b]] /. HoldPattern[If[False, y_, ___]] :> y];
```

The replacement rule with `HoldPattern` looks for the pattern that will arise when the first `If` statement is itself the `Head` wrapping `f`, as will happen when `f` wasn't wrapped by anything else. That's when a recursion would occur, so the argument has to be pulled out through the variable `y`.

Now I get for example:

```
f[1 - 1/2] 5

(* ==> 5/2 *)

f[1 - 1/2] x

(* ==> x (1 - 1/2) *)

f[1 - 1/9]

(* ==> 1 - 1/9 *)
```

This is how I understood the question - I'm not entirely sure if `Defer` was desired or not. Maybe you want to replace `Defer` by `HoldForm`, but the rest wouldn't change.

Comment: Defer was the desired function, but note that the input may not necessarily be numeric. For example, F["a"<>"b"] should output "a"<>"b" while F["a"<>"b"]<>"c" outputs "abc" ...

Comment: I don't think that was clear from the question, and the last result you stated is not the `Defer` result, so I'm still unsure what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Revisiting this question after noticing the third requirement of the question and the statement that you need this only for one function I believe you may want this:

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]

Format[f[x_]] := Defer[x]

f /: Times[f[x_], y_?NumericQ, z___] := (x*y) z
```

Now:

```
f[1 - 1/2]

Times[f[1 - 1/2], 5]

Times[f[1 - 1/2], x]
```

> ```
> 1 - 1/2
>
> 5/2
>
> x (1 - 1/2)
> ```

---

#### Original answer

It seems to me that (at least on version 7) `Unevaluated` behaves as you desire `F` to.
If you do not have a `$Post` or `$PrePrint` function defined a raw `Unevaluated[2+2]` should not evaluate:

> ```
> In[1]:= Unevaluated[2 + 2]
>
> Out[1]= Unevaluated[2 + 2]
> ```

All that remains is to `Format` the output to hide `Unevaluated` itself:

```
Unprotect[Unevaluated]

Format[Verbatim[Unevaluated][expr_]] := Defer[expr]
```

> ```
> In[3]:= Unevaluated[2 + 2]
>
> Out[3]= 2 + 2
> ```

Of course since you said:

> If the solution only works for a specific internal expression, that works, because I only need this for one function.

Verbeia's alluded solution is sufficient:

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll]

Format[f[expr_]] := Defer[expr]

StringJoin[a___, f[inside_], b___] ^:= StringJoin[a, inside, b]
```

Test:

```
f["a" <> "b"]
```

> ```
> "a" <> "b"
> ```

```
f["a" <> "b"] <> "c"
```

> ```
> "abc"
> ```